# What is the meaning of famous?

Tags: meaning

1. Does being a famous author mean that many people will recognise your face when you go to places?
2. Will most of the people know you personally and have a relationship with you?

Comment: What do you think those answers are? Will a famous author who sells millions of books have a personal relationship with all of their readers?

Comment: Before photography, TV etc. a person could be famous without most people knowing what they looked like.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster defines it as "widely known". Exactly how it is well-known is not specific. It might be someone who would be recognized on sight, like Elvis, but not necessarily. Louis Armstrong is also famous, but fewer people would be able to instantly recognize him.

"Famous" just means that many/most people will have heard of the thing, but does not require that they are all well-informed about it or familiar with it.